# Проблема рендеринга компонента React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Всем привет, я только начал изучать React и столкнулся с проблемой. На разных форумах предлагали подключить Babel для parsing jsx, но и это не помогло, а только наоборот вызвало кучу ошибок.

```
<div id='root'></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="render_component.jsx"></script>










    function Welcome(props) {
    return <h1>Привет, {props.name}</h1>;
    }

    const element = <Welcome name="Алиса" />;
    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

В результате я хочу вывести в браузер сообщение Привет, Алиса
Пример был взят из официальной документации React
Суть вопроса: как грамотно отрендерить jsx код, возможно надо подключить что-то или подправить

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего создать проект испльзуя `create-react-app`. В терминале необходимо запустить:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

И в App.js написать:

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Alise" />
    </div>
  );
};

function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Привет, {props.name}</h1>;
}

export default App;
```